# Typescript interface for Rest Props in React (Native)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-props

In REACT with common JS, I can use the spread operator to extract the rest of the properties that I did not declare uniquely.

Like this:

```
function FuncComponent({icon, ...restProps}) {
  //...rest part of function.
    <RandomComp {...restProps} />
}
```

How can I define the interface of the given component in TypeScript?

```
interface FuncComponentProps {
  icon: string;
  /* What is type declaration of the rest props, if there is no 
     any specific props that I can define? */
{
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be bad practice to send down props which you may or may not know. But here is a way to accept all rest props:

```
interface FuncComponentProps {
  icon: string;
  /* The rest of the props */
  [x:string]: any;
{
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) Yes, you are right. It can definitely be an anti-pattern. However, I am working on a PoC and therefore it is not a problem for me.